# Unable to create two different google maps with geoJSON

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I'm attempting to create / instantiate two different maps, each having their own custom pointers (retrieved from geoJSON lines) using google's API.

The problem seems to be that I'm not able to have more than one, and I can't find our why? I'm using two different variable names, and I believe my JSON syntax is all good, atleast I'm not getting any errors.

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/dj2wasdn/1/

Does anyone know whats wrong? Note that by removing line #1709, the second map gets removed, while the first map suddenly get enabled. I can't however, find out why I can't have both of them enabled at the same time.

```
  var map;
  function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: {lat: 60.3913, lng: 5.3221}
      }
    );
```

These (above and below) are my two seperate calls on the constructor, using different variable names.

```
  var map2;
  function initMap() {

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat: 60.3910, lng: 5.3222}
      }
    );
```

Comment: You can't have more than one function with the same name. ([updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dj2wasdn/2/))

Answer (score 0):

You use the same same for two functions. Rename you functions and put them inside a initMap function.

```
initMap1 (){
  // your code for map1
}
initMap2 (){
  // your code for map2
}
// combined two function
initMap() {
  initMap1()
  initMap2()
}
```